# How is sperm stored in the testicles?

Tags: anatomy, testicles, sperm, andrology

I know that men's spermatozoids are stored in testicles and are pumped out during sex or masturbation.

1. If someone needs more and thicker sperm, does it matter how long it has been since one has last ejaculated?
2. Is the sperm always of the same thickness?
3. Does one always ejaculate the same quantity of sperm no matter how often one has sex or masturbates?
4. Biologically, how is the sperm stored in the testicles?